# Como se recuperar de uma Exception e enviar dados da mesma?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exceção

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira pra quando o meu sistema lançar algum tipo de Exception ele se recupere só e me envia um email informando onde ocorreu e qual Exception foi lançada!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ASP.NET captura as exceções não tratadas e disponibiliza-as para tratamento no [evento Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpapplication.error.aspx) da [classe HttpApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) (que representa a aplicação ASP.NET).

Na maioria dos casos essas exceções são inócuas para a aplicação, mas isto não quer dizer que a aplicação recupere automaticamente.

O ASP.NET dispõe de uma infraestrutura para a publicação deste tipo de eventos (e outros). Através do [*health monitoring*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178701.aspx) pode-se publicar os eventos para os mais variados meios como, por exemplo, [Event Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.management.eventlogwebeventprovider.aspx), [base de dados](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.management.sqlwebeventprovider.aspx) [e-mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.management.mailwebeventprovider.aspx) e [outros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.management.webeventprovider.aspx). E se existir o provedor pretendido, pode-se sempre [implementar um provedor à medida](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178716.aspx).

A vantagem de registar os eventos desta forma é que o seu registo e publicação é configurável, não ficando a aplicação agarrada a nenhuma implementação específica. O mesmo evento pode, inclusive, ser publicado para diferentes destinos/provedores.

A minha recomendação é de que nunca se faça isto diretamente na aplicação tratando o evento **Error**.

Comment: Essa foi a melhor resposta que eu já vi sobre o assunto, principalmente por causa do terceiro parágrafo e deste trecho: `o seu registo e publicação é configurável, não ficando a aplicação agarrada a nenhuma implementação específica`. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a classe [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para enviar um e-mail. Para isso, inclua-a no seu arquivo `Global.asax`:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

E use o seguinte código:

```
void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*Obter último erro do servidor e passar a 
    exception como parâmetro do método usado para enviar o e-mail:*/
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    EmailException(ex);
}

private void EmailException(Exception ex)
{
    MailMessage mensagem = new MailMessage();
    mensagem.To.Add("destinatario@servicodeemail.com");
    mensagem.From = new MailAddress("remetente@servicodeemail.com");
    mensagem.Subject = "Assunto do e-mail";
    mensagem.Body = ex.ToString(); //Definindo a exception como corpo do e-mail.

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "Servidor SMTP"; //Definindo servidor smtp. Ex: smtp.gmail.com
    smtp.Send(mensagem); //Envia o e-mail.
}
```

Obs: Caso seu provedor de hospedagem exija **autenticação**, adicione a seguinte linha antes do método `smtp.Send(mensagem)`:

```
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login", "senha");
```

Aproveitando as colocações do Paulo Morgado, você também poderia dar uma olhada nesse artigo de [Como enviar e-mail para notificações de health monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms227553%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).